# Can CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty() be relied on to validate CSS properties?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

The following seems to be consistent on major browsers:

```
const stylesheet = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(stylesheet);

const sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.addRule('.temp', '{}', 0);
const style = sheet.cssRules[0].style;

console.log(style.color); // ""
style.setProperty("color", "*****");
console.log(style.color); // ""
style.setProperty("color", "red")
console.log(style.color); // "red"
```

But I'd like to know: can `style.setProperty("color", "*****")` be relied on to not set the property, or is this just a coincidentally consistent feature on major browsers right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "relied on" you mean is it specified in a standard than yes it is.

The relevant standard is CSSOM and for [setProperty](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty) it says

> 6. Let component value list be the result of parsing value for property property.
> 7. If component value list is null terminate these steps.

and for the [parsing of the value](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#parse-a-css-value) it says

> 1. Let list be the value returned by invoking parse a list of component
>    values from value.
> 2. Match list against the grammar for the property property in the CSS specification.
> 3. If the above step failed, return null.
> 4. Return list.

So providing "*****" is not in the list of allowed color values, null will be returned

Then for [getting `style.color`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-camel-cased-attribute), it says

> The camel-cased attribute attribute, on getting, must return the result of invoking getPropertyValue() with the argument being the result of running the IDL attribute to CSS property algorithm for camel-cased attribute.

and then for [getPropertyValue()](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) it says

> 3. If property is a case-sensitive match for a property name of a CSS declaration in the declarations, return the result of invoking serialize a CSS value of that declaration and terminate these steps.

Finally, null values get serialized as the empty string.